# Tagged dataset with photos for the race/ethnicity detection

Tags: images

Looking for the **tagged dataset**, because I would like to identify **race / ethnicity by photo**. I tried using the UTKFace dataset from Kaggle, but it outputs Hispanic and Arab people on images as `other`. My customer would like those ones as separate categories. Because UTKFace has only 4 tags - `black`, `white`, `indian`, `other`.

Do you have any datasets containing among other things ethnicity? Papers, links, or direction to search or something else would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I believe I found one:

https://github.com/dchen236/FairFace